# Add usermeta on Buddypress register

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

I would like to give to all users who register on my website the value 'Register' of a `usermeta` field which is called **user_type**.

I'm thinking on adding the next code:

`update_user_meta( get_current_user_id()`  or

`$user_id, 'user_type', 'Registrado');`

I'm confused because I don't know on which Buddypress / WordPress function or page I need to paste the code, the idea is setting this value when the user completes the register form.

Comment: I'm looking into inserting the code inside the wp-includes/user.php inside the function  wp_insert_user(). Is this a good idea, also i'm going to edit that on my child theme

Comment: It depends on how you're handling the entire process. Your question really needs more detail (which probably means you need to be farther along in the process). If your question isn't specific, you won't get specific answers.